# Checar se existe um valor em Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá

Tenho uma variável no NodeJS que as vezes vem com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
{ '$instance': {} }
```

e as vezes vem assim:

```
{
 '$instance': { numeropessoas: [ [Object] ] },
  numeropessoas: [ '2' ]
}
```

Como consigo saber (fazer um IF) que cheque se veio com o "numeropessoas"? Preciso saber pois quero tentar pegar o valor dela dessa forma: "step._info.options.numeropessoas[0];" e quando não existe, está me gerando um erro.

Comment: Você pode verificar fazendo `if ('numeropessoas' in step._info.options)`

Answer (score 1):

A partir da versão `14.0` do `Node.js` você pode usar o [encadeamento opcional](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) para obter diretamente o valor que necessita:

```js
const data = {
  '$instance': { numeropessoas: [{ x: 'x' }] },
  numeropessoas: ['2']
};

console.log(data.options?.numeropessoas?.[0]);
```

Caso não exista a propriedade `numeropessoas` ou ela seja nula, o resultado será apenas `undefined`:

```js
const data = {
  '$instance': { numeropessoas: [{ x: 'x' }] }
};

console.log(data.numeropessoas?.[0]);
```

---

> [**Encadeamento opcional**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
>
> O operador de encadeamento opcional `?.` permite a leitura do valor de uma propriedade localizada internamente em uma cadeia de objetos conectados, sem que a validação de cada referência da cadeia seja expressivamente realizada.
>
> O operador `?.` funciona de maneira similar ao operador `.` de encadeamento, exceto que, ao invés de causar um erro se a referência é `nullish (null ou undefined)`, a expressão sofre um "curto-circuito" e retorna com um valor de `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza o [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) que verifica que um objecto tem uma determinada chave:

```js
let var = { '$instance': {} };

var.hasOwnProperty('numeropessoas'); // false


var = {
 '$instance': { numeropessoas: [ [Object] ] },
  numeropessoas: [ '2' ]
};

var.hasOwnProperty('numeropessoas'); // true

// O seu if fica assim
if (var.hasOwnProperty('numeropessoas')) {
  // Tem numeropessoas
} else {
  // Não tem numeropessoas
}
```